# How to use String name with other way

Tags: java

I want with simple way to use a name (String) with not using this code `useUserInput.getString()).equalsIgnoreCase("name"))`.What I mean is, this exercise for example says if it is Stereo-if it is Aerio, etc. I don't want for each one to make user write it. I want to do something to do not to write. With other words it is difficult to understand me maybe, the dog, the cat, the monkey I want to refer to a class like the dog the cat the monkey with not using the expression up. How would you write the down code, differently?

```
static int N; //from keyboard
 static String Typos; // i use userinput string
    public static void main(String[] args) {
   //abstract class Metafores subclasses Stereo-Ygro-Aerio-Meikto
   Metafores[] pin = new Metafores[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pin[i] = new Stereo();
        pin[i+10] = new Ygro();
        pin[i+20] = new Aerio();
        pin[i+30]=new Meikto();
    }


    // exceptions
    System.out.println("An einai Ygro,aeria,meiktou barous tha exoume eksairesh-grapste analoga"); // it is just a message 
              if ((Typos = UserInput.getString()).equalsIgnoreCase("Ygro"))  { // here there is the problem i dont want to make the user to write it
        throw new IllegalExceptionMetaforas("Ta ygra dn metaferontai me aeroplano "); // show the exception 

   }
System.out.println("An einai aeria tha exoume eksairesh");
     if ((Typos = UserInput.getString()).equalsIgnoreCase("aeria"))  {
        throw new IllegalExceptionMetaforas("Ta aeria dn metaferontai me to aeroplano");

   }
     System.out.println("An einai meiktou barous");
     if ((Typos = UserInput.getString()).equalsIgnoreCase("meiktou barous"))  {
        throw new IllegalExceptionMetaforas("Meiktou barous dn metaferontai me to aeroplano");

   }
}
    }
```

Comment: So are you asking how to add attributes such as "name" to your custom classes?

Comment: If you don't want the user (programmer?) to write the string literal (the `"..."` part), where do you want it to come from instead? Or **do** you want the user to write it, as in read it as input from the command line? It's really hard to tell what you're asking here.

Comment: i dont know ,except of the programmer with another way.

Comment: Can you please explain the same with a proper use case.